# Get the last modified set of each set code 10/11/12

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

What I want to do is to retrieve the very first occurrence of these values for each set code:

```
<Root>
<Set>
<Code>10</Code>
<Date>20140405</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>12</Code>
<Date>20140405</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>12</Code>
<Date>20140404</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>11</Code>
<Date>20140404</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>11</Code>
<Date>20140305</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>12</Code>
<Date>20140305</Date>
</Set>
<Set>
<Code>10</Code>
<Date>20140302</Date>
</Set>
</Root>
```

What I want in the result is : I used foreach with sort by date, and `position()`, but didn't get the right results:

```
<Root>
 <Set>
 <Code>10</Code>
 <Date>20140405</Date>
 </Set>
 <Set>
 <Code>12</Code>
 <Date>20140404</Date>
 </Set>
 <Set>
 <Code>11</Code>
 <Date>20140404</Date>
 </Set>
</Root>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* issue - read the defining article: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kLineById" match="Set" use="Code"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Set[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLineById', Code)[1]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```